# Turning a random number generating loop into a one equation?

Tags: math, optimization, pseudocode

Here's some pseudocode:

```
count = 0
for every item in a list
    1/20 chance to add one to count
```

This is more or less my current code, but there could be hundreds of thousands of items in that list; therefore, it gets inefficient fast. (isn't this called like, `0(n)` or something?)

Is there a way to compress this into one equation?

Comment: Doesn't this mean that count is a random variable with mean = list.length/20 and standard deviation = sqrt(19/20/20)/sqrt(list.length) if list.length is large?

Comment: the mean, yes, but I don't know anything about standard deviation and stuff. I stopped taking math the year I would have learned stuff like this. =(

Comment: The number of "lines of code" for a readable answer depends on the language. Nor, for that matter, is "lines of code" normally useful measure of performance.

Comment: Well, that wasn't really the point. I just wanted to not have a loop, basically. I changed my wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the properties of the random variable you've described. Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution):

> The binomial distribution with parameters n and p is the discrete probability distribution of the number of successes in a sequence of n independent yes/no experiments, each of which yields success with probability p.

Let `N` be the number of items in the list, and `C` be a random variable that represents the `count` you're obtaining from your pseudocode. `C` will follow a binomial probability distribution (as shown in the image below), with p = 1/20:

[image]

The remaining problem is how to efficently poll a random variable with said probability distribution. There are a number of libraries that allow you to draw samples from random variables with a specified PDF. I've never had to implement it myself, so I don't exactly know the details, but many are open source and you can refer to the implementation for yourself.

Here's how you would calculate `count` with the [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/) library in Python:

```
n, p = 10, 0.05                  # 10 trials, probability of success is 0.05
count = np.random.binomial(n, p) # draw a single sample
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the OP was asking for a more efficient way to generate random numbers with the same distribution this will give.  I though the question was how to do the exact same operation as the loop, but as a one liner (and preferably with no temporary list that exists just to be iterated over).

---

If you sample a random number generator n times, it's going to have at best O(n) run time, regardless of how the code looks.

In some interpreted languages, using more compact syntax might make a noticeable difference in the constant factors of run time.  Other things can affect the run time, like whether you store all the random values and *then* process them, or process them on the fly with no temporary storage.

None of this will allow you to avoid having your run time scale up linearly with n.

Comment: OP is looking to "compress [the code above]... into one equation", so this is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: @Asad: He says "[list could be big], therefore it gets inefficient fast".  IDK if he thinks making it a oneliner will make it O(1), or if he just means it will avoid actually initializing a temporary list, reducing the constant factor in his O(1).  His last comment on the question says "I just wanted to not have a loop, basically", so I think this answer is very relevant to the OPs misunderstanding of what's slow and what's fast.

Comment: I think by "one-liner" the OP is referring to a closed form expression, i.e. one that produces the result from arithmetic manipulation of a single PRG number. This does not involve iterating over a list of values, so it is O(1). While I don't think this is actually possible, it is certainly possible to improve on the O(n) performance of the naive implementation.

Comment: @Asad: ahhh, I think you're right.  It's also a much better / more interesting question.  I guess that's why she(?) accepted your answer. :)  The question phrasing didn't really ask how to generate a random number from the same distribution, but was written more in terms of expressing the exact same operation as a "one liner"...

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, Peter. I'm pretty inexperienced on using equations/math complicated stuff etc so I don't know how to phrase what I'm asking too well.

Comment: @MackenzieMcClane: You don't need to use technical language.  You could have asked: "How can I efficiently get random numbers that are like the ones I get from <my code>?  My implementation has to call the RNG N times in a loop to get an answer, which is slow for large N."  And if you were feeling computer-sciency, you could say "My implementation is O(N).  Is there a faster way, preferably O(1)?"  Then people who know about this kind of thing can quickly understand that you want a simple formula for turning one or two RNG outputs into what you want, regardless of N.

Comment: Anyway, hope that helps you in your future question-asking. :)  It's impossible to think of all the ways someone might misinterpret the way you phrase a question, esp. if (as is common for obvious reasons) you're asking about something you don't already know about.  But at least try, and maybe include a summary of the question if you feel like you have to say a bunch of other background stuff that might make readers think you're wondering about something else.